# T-SQL update an increasing value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with many columns, one column is called "aID" and currently has no value. I want to add an increasing value here, from 1 to the amount of rows in table.

```
UPDATE [xx].[dbo].[UserValues] 
SET aID = ??
Where aID is null
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe query:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.aID = t.Rn
FROM (SELECT aID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aID) AS Rn   
      FROM [xx].[dbo].[UserValues]
      WHERE aID is null) t
```